# Username still required in custom user model

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to use the new functionality in Django 1.5 to make use of an email address as the username.

Everything is working fine, bar the admin site to update users, which I have had to fiddle with to make passwords not appear raw (and use the password change form etc.) using this code:-

```
class PlayerChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = Player

class PlayerCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Player

class PlayerAdmin(auth.admin.UserAdmin):
    form = PlayerChangeForm
    add_form = PlayerCreationForm

    ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    list_display = ('primkey', 'email', 'mobile')
    list_editable = ('email', 'mobile')

    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'mobile')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_admin')}),
    ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', )}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = ((None, {
    'classes': ('wide',),
    'fields': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
),
    )
    filter_horizontal = ()

    def primkey(self, obj):
       return ("%s" % (obj.get_full_name()))
    primkey.short_description = 'Player'
```

This makes the admin page look fine but when I actually try and update a Player, it tells me there is an error on the form but doesn't indicate where.

After a bit of messing around, it turns out that it wants the username field to be set (if I add that into the admin form, it says this field is required) but surely this isn't the case as I have set my USERNAME_FIELD to be 'email'?

If I set the field to something, I can then save any changes I've made to the other fields but it doesn't save my update to the username field. But really, I don't want to have to set the username at all - I'm using the email as the username.

Any ideas about this or is this a bug in Django?

Answer (score 0):

The [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) states that the forms must be rewritten:

> - UserCreationForm
>
> Depends on the User model. Must be re-written for any custom user model.
>
> - UserChangeForm
>
> Depends on the User model. Must be re-written for any custom user model.

There is a related ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19353 but the code still expect a `username` field to be present.